Storing NodeRef inside Context
Is it possible to store NodeRef inside a Context?
In order to avoid using web_sys library's  document().get_element_by_id() (as it is usually better practice storing refs instead of directly manipulating DOM in frameworks), I wanted to store a NodeRef inside a Context, but that doesn't seem to be possible due to this error:
this method takes 1 argument but 0 arguments were supplied when trying this:
<input type="text"
    node_ref=my_ctx2.input_ref
/>

Please check this codebox link in order to check what's happening.
I can confirm the same error applies to leptos v0.6.11.
Is that a bug or am I missing anything really fundamental?

It seems the node_ref=/_ref= syntax does not handle anything but a single identifier; so an expression like my_ctx2.input_ref doesn't match. Perhaps this is a bug or simple oversight.
Fortunately, NodeRef is trivially copyable so you can simply create another variable:
let input_ref = my_ctx2.input_ref;

view! {
    <input type="text"
        node_ref=input_ref
    />
}

